# How to Create Light-mode & Dark-mode color palettes for change color of page in scss

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i need some help, to create a button in my website to change color of website to dark mode and light mode and i don't know how to create palettes of colors to change all website colors

i create a variable for dark-color and use it in my scss project but it didn't work with just one color variable. and wrong way to do that.

Comment: Have a look at [A Complete Guide to Dark Mode on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/) at CSS-Tricks